# Exception while reading from parquet file

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

We got an exception while reading from parquet file through spark dataframe.

```
sqlContext.read.parquet("parquet_location");
```

Exception is

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: ... is not a Parquet file (too small)  at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:413)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetFileReader.readFooter(ParquetFileReader.java:386)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initializeInternalReader(ParquetRecordReader.java:162)
    at parquet.hadoop.ParquetRecordReader.initialize(ParquetRecordReader.java:145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDD.compute(SqlNewHadoopRDD.scala:126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
```

In the hdfs location "parquet_location" having two .parquet file.
One file having data but another file seems to be empty.

Due to this empty file we are getting this exception.

Any work around for this issue?

Please suggest.

> spark version: 1.6.0

Thanks

Comment: I think you missed the `hdfs://` prefix. Try `"hdfs://<your_location>"`

Comment: "parquet_location" is a hdfs location( hdfs://...).

Comment: In your snippet the `"parquet_location"` is a relative path to a local path `parquet_location`. It's not a variable.

Comment: Is the other file a parquet file ? Can you verfiy this by decoding the file using parquet-tools ? If you have a non parquet file, the read would fail as spark tries to read the footer of the file before it starts reading the file. Missing footer information would throw an error

Comment: @Constantine extension is .parquet but it is zero kb size. And it have a naming format like _complete.parquet.